# Dual citizenship flying back to the country of origin with the intention to stay longer than 90 days

Tags: canada, paperwork, dual-nationality, romanian-citizens

I am going to fly back to my country of origin, Romania, as a Canadian citizen. My Romanian passport has expired and I am planning to renew it when arriving in Romania. If planning to stay longer than 90 days in Romania, do I need to do declare something to the Canadian authorities?

Comment: Man, I hope not.  I'm a Canadian citizen who has lived outside of the country for about ~7000 days now without informing the Canadian authorities, and it honestly never occurred to me to do so.

Comment: Most countries which allow 'dual citizenship' insist that you enter on that countries passport afaik. They couldn't refuse entry to a citizen even with an expired passport (although there might be some administrative hassle). The 'other' country's authorities have no say in the matter.

Comment: @brhans They can fine you if not having a valid passport if the Country requires it; however as pointed out in my answer, Romania accepts expired passports

Comment: What do you imagine might happen if you're outside Canada for over 90 days (or any specific period) without informing Canadian authorities?

Comment: If what you are planning is a "permanent" move out of Canada you may need to report when you became non-resident on next April's tax return so they don't expect you to continue filing them and to account for any exit and non-resident tax liabilities. If you're not doing that but are away for a long time (much longer than 90 days) you could lose eligibility for provincial health insurance and need to deal with that when you get back. Beyond this Canada won't care where you are and there's nothing to tell them.

Answer (score 11):

There's no need to complicate things by entering Romania as a Canadian, being that [expired Romanian passports (or anything proving nationality, including but not limited to ID cards) are accepted for entry](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=RO&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=RO&selDest=Romania&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL)

And no, there's nothing to be declared to the Canadians

Comment: While there is no requirement to register with the Canadian embassy, you may want to do so if you think there is any chance you might require their assistance.